# storing input into Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am learning about arrays , what I wanted to try is first let the user enter x,y values 4 times
e.g

first time

```
x = 1
y = 3
```

second time

```
 x = 2
 y = 3
```

third time

```
 x = 3
 y = 1
```

fourth time

```
 x = 1
 y = 3
```

. and then store the value that the user had key in 4 times inside a array and print them out but I getting some weird outputs.

my output

```
10001711642800 <-- some weird output
```

expected output

```
1,3
2,3
3,1
1,3
```

code(not working)

```
      int x;
      int y;

     //request the user to enter x and y value 4 times.
     for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
        cout << i << "Please enter x-cord." << endl;
        cin >> x;

        cout <<i << "Please enter y-cord." << endl;
        cin >> y;
    }
     //intitalize the array size and store the x,y values   
    int numbers[4][4] = { 
        x, y
    };
    //loop through 4 times to print the values.
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i][i];
    }
```

I know it can be done with vectors but now I am trying with arrays because I am weak in using arrays.

Comment: What type do x and y have? Unless something fancy is going on behind the scenes, each iteration of the input loop overwrites the previously entered values.

Comment: sorry they are both integer type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code:

```
int numbers[4][2];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
   cout<<i<<": Please enter x-cord."<<endl;
   cin>>numbers[i][0];
   cout<<i<<": Please enter y-cord."<<endl;
   cin>>numbers[i][1];
}

for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) 
{
        cout << numbers[i][0]<<"   "<<numbers[i][1];
}
```

Comment: The difference is the for-loop boundaries.  For-loops going through arrays should almost always start at 0, not 1, and continue while less than array size, not less than array size + 1.  Do that and this problem goes away.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing a lot of things here.

1. In your `for`-loop you are overwriting the value stored in `x` and `y` at each iteration of the loop.
2. `int numbers[4][4]` creates a two-dimensional array containing a total of 16 elements. What you want is `int numbers[4][2]`.
3. Your array initialization is incomplete, because `x` and `y` only contain the last two values the user has entered, not all 8.

To fix this, you should create the array before the `for`-loop and then store the values the user enters directly into the array.

Answer (score 2):

You're not storing the input received from the user in any array. They're overwritten again and again in the loop. Store them in an array and then display it.

```
 //intitalize the array size and store the x,y values   
int numbers[4][4] = { 
    x, y
};
```

This is not required. Since you're going to overwrite the contents of the array you needn't initialize them with some random variables. In fact the variables `x` and `y` are not at all required.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // you need 4 arrays of 2 numbers, not 4x4 but 4x2
    int numbers[4][2] = { { } };        // initialize all of them to 0
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "x = ";
        std::cin >> numbers[i][0];      // store the input directly in the array
        std::cout << "y = ";            // instead of using a dummy
        std::cin >> numbers[i][1];
    }

    // display array contents
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << numbers[i][0] << ", " << numbers[i][1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to declare the variable you need to fill;

```
 // A new data type which holds two integers, x and y
 struct xy_pair {
     int x;
     int y;
 };

 // A new array of four xy_pair structs
 struct xy_pair numbers[4];
```

Then, you can begin filling it.

```
 //request the user to enter x and y value 4 times.
 for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    cout << i << "Please enter x-cord." << endl;
    cin >> numbers[i].x;

    cout <<i << "Please enter y-cord." << endl;
    cin >> numbers[i].y;
}
```

Then, you can print it!

```
//loop through 4 times to print the values.
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    cout << "X is " << numbers[i].x << " and Y is " << numbers[i].y << endl;
}
```

PS! I haven't run the code myself, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for your snippet. I got an idea for what to do already